# Initializing baseclass within a class' __init__ method

Tags: python, serial-port

Here's a class I created to communicate with a device called "Waveplate". The "Waveplate" class inherits the attributes and methods of the serial.Serial Baseclass. But as you see, the baseclass serial.Serial needs to be initialized. What I have done below works, my question is, is this the most elegant way?

```
import time
import serial

class WavePlate(serial.Serial):
""" This class returns an instance that contains the attributes and methods of a ``serial.Serial`` object.     
"""
    def __init__(self, p, brate):
        """Here's the constructor. """
        self.p = p
        self.brate = brate

        serial.Serial.__init__(self, port=self.p, baudrate=self.brate, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, 
                          stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
```

Comment: [Python's `super()` considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Comment: Usually, you call the base class `__init__` first, then do whatever is left for the child class. It strikes me as suspicious that you are explicitly setting `self.p` and `self.brate`, *then* passing the same values to `Serial.__init__`.

Comment: Thanks guys.. super() sounds super amazing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `super`:

In python 3:

```
class WavePlate(serial.Serial):
""" This class returns an instance that contains the attributes and methods of a ``serial.Serial`` object.     
"""
    def __init__(self, p, brate):
        """Here's the constructor. """
        self.p = p
        self.brate = brate

        super().__init__(port=self.p, baudrate=self.brate, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
```

In python 2:

```
class WavePlate(serial.Serial):
""" This class returns an instance that contains the attributes and methods of a ``serial.Serial`` object.     
"""
    def __init__(self, p, brate):
        """Here's the constructor. """
        self.p = p
        self.brate = brate

        super(WavePlate, self).__init__(port=self.p, baudrate=self.brate, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
```

**Note**: Most of the time, you want call the superclass constructor before making any declaration in your child constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I have removed the instance attributes that were being passed onto the baseclass initialization step